# Normalized ecommerce data model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So there's not much here to "normalize" the database (really only the `OrderItems` class and maybe the Table Meta class as well) but I'm relatively happy with it.

My only concern is the repeated `Name` property in many of the tables but since it doesn't appear in all tables, it doesn't make sense to me to put it in the meta.

```
namespace Ortund.Store
{
    // Used to avoid repetition of comment properties.
    // This class won't be included in the DbSet
    // I know the naming sucks
    public class TableMeta
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category : TableMeta
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subcategory : TableMeta
    {
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order : TableMeta
    {
        public string Number { get; set; } // I'd have called it OrderNumber but that seemed redundant
        public User User { get; set; }
        public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public bool Paid { get; set; }
        public bool Delivered { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderItem : TableMeta
    {
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product : TableMeta
    {
        public Subcategory Category { get; set; } // naming might be confusing?
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }

    // would use ASP.NET Identity but all the blog posts I've found about
    // how to use it are out of date
    public class User : TableMeta
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; } // bcrypt secured
        public string Token { get; set; } // bcrypt secured - used to reset password
    }

    public class Wishlist : TableMeta
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Used to avoid repetition of comment properties._ - what are those? I see only `Id`.

Comment: Yes, there is only 1 common property but in case later work on the data model creates any more it would be more efficient in the code-behind at least to place them there

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not particularly a bad idea (or maybe it is?) but it isn't a good one either.

You make the models more complex just to save one or two properties. Those are just simple data models so leave them simple.

An abstraction like the `TableMeta` should have a purpose so you can use it for something meaningful like dependency injection but can you? No, you cannot. `TableMeta` on its own does not mean anything and is completely useless - even as a raw data model.